# Determine if a number contains a digit in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to write a function that takes in a list, and for each number in the list I would like it to check if there is the digit 5 in it. If the digit 5 is in the number it would print true and move on to the next number in the list until the end

Example is the list [155 12 14 6 254 15]

155 prints true as there is a 5 in it

12 prints false as there is no 5 in it

etc..

This is what I have done so far

```
proc containsDigit {l} {
    foreach nxt $l {

    while {$nxt!= 0} {
    set int [expr {fmod($nxt, 10)}]

    if {$int == 5 } {
        puts "true"
            }else{
                set $nxt [expr {$nxt/10}]
            }
        puts false

    }

    }
}

set a [list 155 12 14 6 254 15]
containsDigit $a
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to treat the number as a string and use `string first` or `string match`. I prefer `string match`.

```
proc containsDigit {l} {
    foreach nxt $l {
        if {[string match *5* $nxt]} {
            puts "true"
        } else {
            puts "false"
        }
    }
}
```

If the numbers are possibly hexadecimal but you want to only ever search the decimal form, condition the string to search by using `format %d`:

```
proc containsDigit {l} {
    foreach nxt $l {
        if {[string match *5* [format "%d" $nxt]]} {
            puts "true"
        } else {
            puts "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using fmod(), the integer modulo operator should be used:

set int [expr {$nxt % 10}]

You need to `break` out of the loop when the 'true' condition is found.  If there
is a 5 present, you don't want to look further.

The syntax here is wrong:

```
 set $nxt [expr {$nxt/10}]
```

This will, for example, set the variable `12` to `1`.
You want:

```
 set nxt [expr {$nxt/10}]
```